# Drupal 7 pass a custom form fileds input as arguments to the url on submit

Tags: 7, forms, redirection, uri

How can I pass fields input as arguments to the url on custom form submit? I tried the following:

```
function custom_form_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Location'),
    '#options' => location_options(),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit';
  return $form;
}

function location_options() {
  return array(
    'to' => 'To USA',
    'within' => 'Within USA',
  );
}

function custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // I need a function here to redirect to a url with something like
  // move-quote?location=to
  // I tried $form_state['redirect'] but didn't work
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'move-quote',
    array(
     'query' => array(
       'move-quote' => $form_state['values']['location'],
     ),
    'fragment' => 'optional',
  ),
);
```

should work in your submit function. Try also

```
$form['#submit'][0] = 'custom_form_submit';
```

and clear your caches.
Also http://drupal.org/node/291680 was helpful

Comment: last exit, but may have problems

drupal_goto()

Comment: Sweet, Cheers m8